# Nginx does not execute php files on WSL. How can i fix this?

Tags: php, nginx, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) on Windows 10 and i installed Nginx and php7.2-fpm and created a simple php file `index.php` with `echo` statement content.
I used `sudo php </directory/to/index.php>` to test php so it's working correctly. Also, when i start Nginx and navigate to `localhost` The "Welcome To Nginx!" page is displayed. But, When i navigate to server domain, "This site can’t be reached" is displayed by browser.
How can i fix this problem?

#### server block configuration file:

```
server {
    listen       80;

    server_name  site.local;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/laragadgetstore.com.access.log  main;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/site.local;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_buffering off;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

In the `nginx.conf`, i changed user to www-data and in `/etc/hosts` file i defined 127.0.0.1 to the server domain. Also, i changed the ownership of conf.d and server domain root directory to the www-data!
Also, in `error.log` file for Nginx, the last error is:

```
[emerg] 1837: io_setup() failed (38: Function not implemented)
```

This error is recorded only when i restart Nginx.
I do not know what to do to get this going!!

Comment: I finally found the solution. I just should to set `fastcgi_buffering` to `off` in server block configuration. Special thanks to @hparadiz on GitHub.[link](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/393)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. I modified default file under

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available to use port 8081
```

**Code:**

```
server {
    listen **8081** default_server;
    listen [::]:**8081** default_server;
    // ...
}
```